# How to write SQL query with division in this example?

Tags: sql, mysqli

I need help with writing the SQL query for the question stated below. I assume I have to use division but i have just no idea of how to do it.

Assume the following relations: S (for suppliers), SP (for deliveries) and P (for parts) 
Answer the following question by writing queries in SQL:

) Which suppliers supply only parts from London?

Note that the question asks for only parts from London and not every supplier that supplies a part from London.

```
S:
S#   SNAME  CITY
S7   Lowen  Berlin 
S8   Jeter  N.Y. 
S9   Kling  Berlin

SP:
S#  P#  QTY
S7  P2  300  
S7  P3  400  
S8  P2  300  
S9  P4  500

P:
P#  NAME  COLOR CITY
P1  Bolt  Blue  Berlin
P3  Nut   Red   Paris 
P2  Cog   Red   Rome 
P4  Screw Green Paris
```

Comment: This is homework! Work it out yourself!

Comment: Well, I wouldn't be as rude as Kevin, but you should at least show what you tried, and where you've got problems. Tip : GROUP BY and HAVING COUNT(xxx) could be your friends. I don't see where you could use division.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus This question has been asked because user1955754 has got a school/college/university assignment and cannot be bothered to learn basic SQL.

Comment: @KevinBrydon well, that's a point of view. You've probably been at school, have probably been stuck one day or another. Asking for a ready-made solution is certainly not a good idea... but we've just different ways to say that ;)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously in your example there are no such suppliers as soon as there are no parts from London.
Try to use following query:

```
SELECT S.S#,max(S.SNAME) from S
LEFT JOIN SP on (S.S#=SP.S#)
LEFT JOIN P on (SP.P# = P.P#)
GROUP BY  S.S#
HAVING MAX(P.CITY)='London' and MIN(P.CITY)='London'
```

Comment: Nice.  I like the min and max to get solutions with parts from London, but excluding those with parts from elsewhere.

Comment: Oh i see what you did there! Thanks!